# Chained or Dependent Select Zend_Form jQuery to remove or replace the form elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework

I have been using Zend Framework 1 to create a dependent/chained Zend_Form.

When a `Zend_Form_element_Select` another Zend_Form_Element_Select is added to the form with correct fields dependant on the first select's value.

So I add the new Select with a:

```
$("#city-label").before(data);
```

which will insert the new select before the city label.

The problem arises when the first select's value is changed again. Then a new Select is added to the form. I would Ideally like the old `satellite element` that is the label and the select to be removed.

```
<dt id="satellite-label">
<label for="satellite" class="optional">Satelite</label>
</dt>
<dd class="ui-select">
<select name="satellite" id="satellite">
    <option value="--Select One--" label="--Select One--">--Select One--</option>
    <option value="5" label="Alex">Alex</option>
    <option value="6" label="Patro">patro</option>
    <option value="7" label="Zozo ">Zozo</option>
</select></dd>
<dt id="city-label"><label for="city" class="optional">City</label></dt>
```

And then replaced with the new element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from within your AJAX **success**:

```
$("#satellite-label").remove();
$("#satellite").parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep track of the new element so you can remove it when the value changes again:

```
var currentLabel;

...

if (currentLabel) {
    currentLabel.remove();
}
currentLabel = $(data);
$("#city-label").before(currentLabel);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
$("#satellite_elem-label").remove();
$("#satellite_elem").parent().remove();;
$("#city-label").before(newElement);
```

Comment: This is a legitimate way and seemingly the most elegant, however the answer is a composite of the previous 2 answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden input (`Zend_Form_Element_Hidden`) then simply replace the hidden element.

```
$("#target-element").html(data);
```

Don't forget to use same id (`target-element`) on html content of `data`.

This way you can also add backend validators to this hidden element to use `isValid` method.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove previous inserted select before insert another on first select's value is changed again.

So it may be help in your case.

```
$("#city-label").prev('.ui-select').remove();
$("#city-label").prev('#satellite-label').remove();
$("#city-label").before(data);
```

or simply add this

```
$("#city-label").prev().remove();
$("#city-label").prev().remove();
$("#city-label").before(data);
```

It will remove select then label and insert new select before insert new one.